# After uninstalling Docker from RHEL, having issues with removing associated files

Tags: docker, rhel, device-mapper

I installed Docker EE on RHEL. Now when I need to uninstall, as per the instructions on [the Docs](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ee/rhel/#uninstall-docker-ee), i need to run `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/docker`.
This however gives me the following errors:

`rm: cannot remove ‘/var/lib/docker/plugins/11d2935e42e055dda59b62977de0c00bb18d820c6eccdff964f232276a6e7cd7/rootfs/dev’: Device or resource busy
rm: cannot remove ‘/var/lib/docker/plugins/11d2935e42e055dda59b62977de0c00bb18d820c6eccdff964f232276a6e7cd7/rootfs/etc/resolv.conf’: Device or resource busy
rm: cannot remove ‘/var/lib/docker/plugins/11d2935e42e055dda59b62977de0c00bb18d820c6eccdff964f232276a6e7cd7/rootfs/etc/hosts’: Device or resource busy
rm: cannot remove ‘/var/lib/docker/plugins/11d2935e42e055dda59b62977de0c00bb18d820c6eccdff964f232276a6e7cd7/rootfs/proc’: Device or resource busy
rm: cannot remove ‘/var/lib/docker/plugins/11d2935e42e055dda59b62977de0c00bb18d820c6eccdff964f232276a6e7cd7/rootfs/run/docker’: Device or resource busy
rm: cannot remove ‘/var/lib/docker/plugins/11d2935e42e055dda59b62977de0c00bb18d820c6eccdff964f232276a6e7cd7/rootfs/sys’: Device or resource busy
rm: cannot remove ‘/var/lib/docker/devicemapper’: Device or resource busy`

How should I go about completely removing these files?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, there are still active mounts, and perhaps even a running container.  The easiest way to get rid of them would be to reboot the machine.  Otherwise, you'll have too look carefully at `ps` and `mount` output to determine what's running and what's mounted, and terminate those processes and unmount the file systems.

(If there is a bind mount in play, you are lucky that `rm -rf` did not damage the host installation.)

Comment: As I mentioned, I have removed docker using yum uninstall already. So there are no active mounts and no running containers. This is the second step.

Comment: Clearly, `yum uninstall` failed to terminate all the running processes.